# send data to an object in another html from nodejs server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using Iframe in html5 to display an html page inside an html page. Can I possibly call an object that is not in the main html file but instead in the linked html file?

Comment: You want to access some data available in inner html from main html right?. Can you give more information? Maybe a piece of code or be more explicit in what you want to do?. Is the main html in the same server as the inner html? What kind of object do you want to get access to, a json object or a js object with methods, etc?

Comment: inner html is the same server with the main html. Already got the answer and it can be done when they are listening to the same port. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, with some security restrictions.

Direct interaction between two frames of the [same origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) is allowed mostly without restriction.

Communication between different origins (different ports, schemes, or hosts) is much more restricted because of security concerns. Still, you can communicate across origins safely using `Window.postMessage()` ([MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)).

Comment: I was thinking that would be the case but not so sure myself so I asked. Thank you very much!